# What are the best practices to deploy and host artifacts for a Docker Multicontainer environment in Elasticbeanstalk for Scala Apps?

Tags: scala, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerhub, sbt-docker

I have several Scala applications that I want to deploy in a Docker multi-container environment on Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk.

It seems like the whole process is a bit more complicated that I was expecting. **So I'm really looking forward to hear some feedback for best practices and other ways to improve my entire process and be able to "automate" some steps (if possible).**

This is my current process:

1. To generate my projects' artifacts I'm using the [sbt-docker](https://github.com/marcuslonnberg/sbt-docker) plugin. This
   plugin generates the projects artifacts (jars and Dockerfile) under
   [app-route]/target/docker.
2. I upload these artifacts (jars and Dockerfile) into a git
   repository (currently doing this "manually").
3. As [Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk requires for Docker
   multi-containers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html#create_deploy_docker_ecs_images), I need an online repository to "host" the
   images: Could be [Docker-Hub](https://hub.docker.com) or [Quay.io](https://quay.io). Either require me
   to have a git repository in which it can find the artifacts to be
   able to generate the project's image.
4. Having created the multi-container environment in Elastic Beanstalk,
   I proceed to upload the [Dockerrun.aws.json](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html#create_deploy_docker_v2config_dockerrun) file as detailed in
   Amazon's documentation and also the
   .ebextensions/elb-listeners.config file with the settings of the
   ports (Since I'm running multiple apps)
5. Magic! Amazon generates my environment. Same url, different ports
   for all my apps (as specified in the configuration files in *step
   4*.

**I would love to find a way to automate *step 2*.** **Since this requires me to have an extra repo per each app. I have my apps hosted in a git repo, and I have an "extra" repo per each where I host the artifacts generated in *step 1* to be able to do *step 3*.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to use a different SBT plugin for step 1, then you can automate step 2.

Although quay.io supports building your image from GitHub, they *do not require it*.  (You can publish a local Docker image directly to your quay.io repository.)

1. Use the [sbt-native-packager plugin](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html#tasks) in project/plugins.sbt.
2. Setup the plugin settings in build.sbt, like: `dockerRespository := Some("quay.io/myaccount")`
3. Your step 1 becomes: `sbt docker:stage`
4. Followed by: `sbt docker:publishLocal`
5. Check your image names and tags with `docker images`.  The new image should have a name like `quay.io/myaccount/app`
6. Before you can publish to quay.io, you must `docker login quay.io`.  Read [their tutorial](https://quay.io/tutorial/).
7. Your step 2 becomes `sbt docker:publish`.  Now your quay.io account should contain the same IMAGE ID as your local Docker daemon.

Proceed with steps 3+ on the AWS side...

Answer (score 0):

I am not really familiar with Scala however I believe the artifacts could be generated by Jenkins/CircleCI inside of your container that is built on Jenkins/CircleCI then the appropriate image tags referenced within your Dockerrun.aws.json.

Hope that helps.